# got error on android with eclipse: no target available

Tags: android, eclipse

i install all the programs that need for develop on android

i start project like this:

File - new - project - android - android project > next

but in build target i see: `no target available`

what can be the problem ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You probably didn't set the path to the Android SDK in eclipse yet.**

Go to `Window -> Preferences -> Android` and enter the path to your SDK into the *SDK Location* textfield at the top.

**You have no Android platforms installed**

In this case go to
`Window -> SDK and AVD Manager -> Available Packages -> Android Repository` and select a few targets¹, then click install. You can check for already installed platforms on the left under `Installed packages` if you are not sure.

The targets you are looking for are the `SDK Platform Android X.X , API Y, rev Z` ones.
If you don't want to download much, I'd say get `Android 2.3.3., API 10` and `Android 3.2, API 13`. 2.3.3. is the most recent phone version of Android, and 3.2 is the newest tablet version.

¹ *If you got a decent internet connection I'd recommend to get everything, you will need a few target platforms sooner or later anyway.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to select a build target in that dialog, e.g. Google APIs 2.2. That dialog is a little confusing, because it has a scroll pane in it, which is easy to overlook. You need to scroll down to get to some options.